# AngularJS filter array of objects, including nested array, with value from <input>

Tags: angularjs, search, input, filter, arrayobject

**I have such array of objects:**

```
var cars = [  
   {  
      "carMake":"Audi",
      "models":[  
         "A4",
         "A6",
         "R8"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "carMake":"BMW",
      "models":[  
         "3er",
         "X3",
         "i8",
         "7er"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "carMake":"Toyota",
      "models":[  
         "Corolla",
         "Auris",
         "Yaris",
         "Gt86",
         "Rav4"
      ]
   }
];
```

**And I have tried below AngularJS code for searching:**

```
$scope.searching = '';
$scope.producers = [];
$scope.models = [];

$scope.searchCar = function() {
  $scope.producers = $filter('filter')(cars, function(value) {
    return value.carMake === $scope.searching;
  });
  $scope.models = $filter('filter')(cars, function(value) {
    return angular.forEach(value.models, function(model) {
      return model === $scope.searching;
    });
  });
};
```

**Inside HTML I have:**

```
<label>What do you want to find?
  <input type="text" ng-model="searching" ng-change="searchCar()" placeholder="Search...">
</label>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="producer in producers">{{producer}}</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="model in models">{{model}}</li>
</ul>
```

My code doesn't work as I expected - it only outputs whole `cars` Array element. For example, when I type "Audi" i got whole "Audi object", although I want separately results for car producers and/or car models that match pattern inside `<input>`.

I want searching to work like, when I type "Au" then I will see "Audi" in first list and "Auris" in the second. So searching should work as well for `cars.carMake` as for `cars.models[]` and present result in both lists (first/left for car producers and second/right for car models).

Comment: have you tried angular inbuilt filter? it's search function for arrays?

Comment: @JorawarSingh, according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter I am using JavaScript way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to store the items in separated arrays, then use the `filter` in view:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.sensitiveCompare = sensitiveCompare;
    var cars = [  
       {  
          "carMake":"Audi",
          "models":[  
             "A4",
             "A6",
             "R8"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "carMake":"BMW",
          "models":[  
             "3er",
             "X3",
             "i8",
             "7er"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "carMake":"Toyota",
          "models":[  
             "Corolla",
             "Auris",
             "Yaris",
             "Gt86",
             "Rav4"
          ]
       }
    ];

    $scope.producers = cars.map(function(car) {
      return car.carMake;
    });

    $scope.models = [];
    
    cars.forEach(function(car) {
      $scope.models = $scope.models.concat(car.models);
    });


    function sensitiveCompare(input, search) {
      return ('' + input).indexOf('' + search) > -1;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>What do you want to find?
    <input type="text" ng-model="searching" ng-change="searchCar()" placeholder="Search...">
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="producer in producers | filter: searching: sensitiveCompare" ng-bind="producer"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="model in models | filter: searching: sensitiveCompare" ng-bind="model"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

If you really want to create your *custom* `function` for this, check this:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.searchCar = searchCar;
    var cars = [  
       {  
          "carMake":"Audi",
          "models":[  
             "A4",
             "A6",
             "R8"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "carMake":"BMW",
          "models":[  
             "3er",
             "X3",
             "i8",
             "7er"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "carMake":"Toyota",
          "models":[  
             "Corolla",
             "Auris",
             "Yaris",
             "Gt86",
             "Rav4"
          ]
       }
    ];
    
    $scope.producers = [];
    $scope.models = [];
    
    function searchCar() {
      $scope.producers = $filter('filter')(cars, function(car) {
        return car.carMake.indexOf($scope.searching) !== -1;
      });
      
      $filter('filter')(cars, function(car) {
        $scope.models = car.models.filter(function(model) {
          return model.indexOf($scope.searching) !== -1;
        })
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>What do you want to find?
    <input type="text" ng-model="searching" ng-change="searchCar()" placeholder="Search...">
  </label>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="producer in producers" ng-bind="producer.carMake"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="model in models" ng-bind="model"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, but why You propose using `filter` in HTML instead of using `$filter` in JavaScript? Additional question - how to filter including case sensitiveness?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer since Angular already can do it for me, for what should I write my own `method`? To include case sensitive compare you should add a little method as I added above. Check it please.

Comment: Thank You. Could You also show "alternative" way with using `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator, anyPropertyKey)` presented at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter as I was trying to filter it using `$filter`?